# Create file in memory not filesystem

Tags: c#, .net, file

I am using a .NET library function that uploads files to a server, and takes as a parameter a path to a file.  The data I want to send is small and constructed at runtime.  I can save it to a temporary file and then upload it.

Since my application will be deployed in a variety of environments, and I don't know if I'll be able to create the temporary file reliably, it would be preferable to be able to pass in a path to a virtual file in memory.

I can't change the library; I know it executes the following on the file:

```
LibraryUploadFunction(string filename) {
    fileName = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to avoid writing the file to disk?

Thanks

**Edit:**

The library call is Webclient.UploadFile, as pointed out in the answers, there are many workarounds possible, including using alternative libraries, of which there are many.

Comment: I cringe when a library naively only works with files on disk. A file is a named sequence of bytes, so in the name of all things holy, accept a stream and a string for the name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, your library is fundamentally inflexible in this aspect, by the fact that it uses `FileStream`.

Options:

- Use a ramdrive and specify a path on that, in order to avoid actually hitting disk
- Depending on where the library comes from, either request a change (if it's closed source) or just *make* the change if it's open source
- Use a different library. (What's special about this one?)

Answer (score 7):

If the library exposes another method accepting a `Stream`, you could use a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx).

If it accepts a `SafeFileHandle`, you could use a [`MemoryMappedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx).

Otherwise, you'll have to be satisfied with a file on disk.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use one of the other `WebClient.Upload*` methods. For example, if you have your data in a `byte[]`, use [`UploadData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbyy24ds.aspx).

Another option, if you want to upload the data as a stream is to use [`OpenWrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e03etwyx.aspx).

Comment: I did try UploadString, and now I've tried UploadData.  Both caused the server I was communicating with to reboot :-(.  I could dig into the format of the POST that WebClient makes to figure out exactly where the problem is, but that would defeat the purpose of using a simple http client like WebClient.  Temporary files it is!

Comment: @Stefan It caused your server to *reboot*? Then there is something very wrong with your server and you should figure out what it is.

Comment: Hehe...it's not "my" server as such.  It's a network connected embedded device, which is out of my control.  There are thousands of these things in the field.  So pretty much I'm stuck with sending requests in a format it likes. At least I know of one way to get data to it successfully, so I can live with that!