How to pass an in-memory-file address to another function in .NET
I have an in-memory file called byte[] FileContent and a third-party package ( FFMPEG in my case) that converts the given input file and saves it into the output directory:
FFMPEGCore.Join("/path/to/output.mp4", "path/to/input.mp4");

Unfortunately, at the API level, I cannot writes by byte [] into a file, so I was wondering if there's a way to keep everything in-memory and pass the address of my in-memory input, output to FFMPEGCore.Join?

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45899585/pipe-input-in-to-ffmpeg-stdin/45902691#45902691

Doesn't look like it - https://github.com/rosenbjerg/FFMpegCore/blob/1c4333ee4c3481050078ad3e65695d6b674685a1/FFMpegCore/FFMpeg/FFMpeg.cs#L253

I cannot writes by byte [] into a file - why not?

Jon Skeet said no: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16359983/6196568

According to this you can write .FromPipeInput(new StreamPipeSource(inputStream))
Example:
byte[] FileContent = ...;
using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(FileContent);
await FFMpegArguments
    .FromPipeInput(new StreamPipeSource(memoryStream))
    .OutputToFile(...)
    .ProcessAsynchronously();

